# Rails using localhost instead of remote ip host to connect to mysql2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql2

When attempting to use a remote mysql database with rails, it ignores the host parameter in the database.yml file and attempts instead to connect to the local server name. I have sanitized the info below with XXX and localservername.

Below is the database.yml entry for development:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: temp_admin_development
  username: XXX
  password: XXX
  host: 10.X.X.X
  port: 3306
```

Here is the error we get when running rake db:create:

```
rake aborted!
Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'XXX'@'localservername' to database 'temp_admin_development': CREATE DATABASE `temp_admin_development` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET `utf8` COLLATE `utf8_unicode_ci`
```

Here is a manual attempt to connect via irb:
    Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "10.X.X.X", :username => "XXX")

```
Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'XXX'@'localservername' (using >password: NO)
    from /home/XXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `connect'
    from /home/XXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `initialize'
    from (irb):2:in `new'
    from (irb):2
    from /home/XXX/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

Notice it is attempting to connect to the local server name and ignoring the host parameter being passed.

Comment: We found the issue. The host was actually being pulled in correctly. The problem was that we had to specify a database that already existed in mysql, not a new one. Once that was specified the rake db:migrate worked.

Answer (score 1):

We found the issue. The host was actually being pulled in correctly. The problem was that we had to specify a database that already existed in mysql, not a new one. Once that was specified the rake db:migrate worked.